# Is there more than one kind of debuggers?

Tags: debugging

Is there a way to find bugs in code, beyond using a classic debugger? I mean, a classic debugger can:

- Break execution on breakpoints (set by a programmer);
- Break execution on errors (exceptions in .NET);
- Show and change values of visible variables (when the execution is paused).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is some other method I have included

- Code review: Having other developers review your code can help
  identify potential bugs.
- Logging: Adding logging statements to your code can help you track
  the flow of execution and identify where errors are occurring.
- Unit testing: Writing automated tests for individual units of code
  can help you catch bugs before they make it into production.
- Integration testing: Testing how different units of code work
  together can help you find bugs that may not be present in individual
  units.
- Performance profiling: Analyzing the performance of your code can
  help you identify bottlenecks and optimize your code.
- Fuzz Testing: This is a technique of providing random inputs to the
  software to test how it handles unexpected inputs.
- Static analysis: This process analyzes the code without executing it
  to find potential issues.
- Code coverage: This measures how much of the code is executed during
  testing.
- These are some of the common methods, however there are a lot more
  techniques that can be used depending on the requirements,
  complexity, and type of application.

Comment: Thanks, now I have a big list of debugging techniques.

Comment: OK, if it's important for you :)